# How to calculate the average within an array of struct?

Tags: c++

So my question has to deal with the calculate average function in my code. The function takes in the statistics_array and a semester_index. This function loops through the grades_array in the struct indicated by the semester_index and sums all the grades. This sum is divided by the no_of _grades in the member struct (indexed by semester_index) to compute the average grade for that semester's final exam.  Finally, this average is stored in the average_grade member of the struct indexed by the semester_index.

The problem is how do I do this is my code I created a variable name sum to add on to this but that method is not working how do I fix this error my code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct ExamType {
    string semester_name;
    int year;
    int num_grades;
    float average_grade;
    int grades_above_average;
    int grades_below_average;
    int grades_array[35];
};

void input_data(ExamType[], ifstream&);
void calculate_statistics(ExamType[]);
void print_results(ExamType[]);
void calculate_average(ExamType[], int);
void calculate_above_average(ExamType[], int);
void calculate_below_average(ExamType[], int);


int main()
{
    char make_type;
    ifstream myfile;
    ExamType statistics_array[5];
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    input_data(statistics_array,myfile);
}

void input_data(ExamType statistics_array[], ifstream& myfile)
{
    int num_students;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].semester_name;
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].year;
        myfile >> num_students;
        statistics_array[i].num_grades=num_students;
        for (int j = 0; i < num_students; i++) {
            myfile >> statistics_array[j].grades_array[i];
        }
    }
}

void calculate_statistics(ExamType statistics_array[])
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        calculate_average(statistics_array, index);
        calculate_above_average(statistics_array, index);
        calculate_below_average(statistics_array, index);
    }
}

void calculate_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
    {
      statistics_array[index].grades_array+sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think this line does? `statistics_array[index].grades_array+sum;`

Comment: I think that it adds the value for that specific index in the array struct to the sum integer value is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  Precisely and nothing more.

Comment: OK thanks i that this was wrong for sum reason.

Comment: It sums them together and *discards the result*.

Comment: @RichardOkpala, perhaps you mean `statistics_array[index].grades_array += sum;` instead (to add it to the field `grades_array`, and **store it there**) ???

Answer (score 2):

```
statistics_array[index].grades_array+sum;
```

This line does nothing to any of your variables. You're basically saying:

```
void foo(){
    /*some stuff*/
    1+1;
}
```

See what I'm getting at? You're not assigning the value calculated anywhere, so the outcome of the aforementioned line is not stored anywhere.

To fix this, change the line into

```
sum += statistics_array[index].grades_array;
```

or

```
sum = sum + statistics_array[index].grades_array;
```

But this is not the only error, since grades_array is an array, and you are trying to add it to a normal int. So you have to specify an index within grades_array.

```
sum += statistics_array[index].grades_array[another_index];
```

Comment: I get an error when i do that my code that i had is.

Comment: Edited my answer, seems like I completely missed another error.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your function like this to calculate the average and save it to `average_grade`.

```
void calculate_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index) {
    float sum = 0;
    int n = statistics_array[index].num_grades; // total no. of grades
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += statistics_array[index].grades_array[i]; // summing all grades
    }
    statistics_array[index].average_grade = sum/n; // average = total_sum / (num_of_grades)
}
```

Note: I recommend using float for `sum` as the average is a float, so that the calculation will result in a float value, or typecast it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
> {
>   statistics_array[index].grades_array + sum;
> }
> ```

You are adding `statistics_array[index].grades_array` to `sum`, but you aren't storing the value anywhere. Judging from your question, I'm assuming that you need to increment `statistics_array[index].grades_array` to `sum` at every iteration of the for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
{
    sum += statistics_array[index].grades_array[i];
}
```

Comment: Here you're still adding an array to a regular int.

Answer (score 0):

While all these solutions using a for-loop work, I suggest to use one of the standard algorithms (albeit in the `<numeric>` header) instead: `std::accumulate`.

With its help you can rewrite `calculate_average` as

```
void calculate_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index) {
    auto const n = statistics_array[index].num_grades;
    auto const sum
        = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(statistics_array[index].grades_array),
                          std::cend(statistics_array[index].grades_array),
                          0);

    statistics_array[index].average_grade = static_cast<float>(sum)/n;
}
```